# Getting StatusCallback events from Twilio in Java only

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying out sms and calls from Twilio. I am able to send sms and make calls from my Java code. But I am not getting how can I get status callback in the same Java code.

Is there any way I can get status callback events in my java code?

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallback", "https://www.myapp.com/events"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackMethod", "POST"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "initiated"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "ringing"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "answered"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StatusCallbackEvent", "completed"));
```

Also, is there any way we can give the TwiML data (the xml for voice calls) in the function calling function from Java, instead of giving it a URL to the TwiML/XML file.
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));

```
CallFactory callFactory = client.getAccount().getCallFactory();
Call call = callFactory.create(params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio performs [status callbacks as webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#asynchronous), much like you get when you [receive an incoming call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request) or [message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request). In order to receive these webhooks your application will need to be reachable by Twilio.

If you are having difficulty with that locally, then you might be interested in checking out [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) which is [a great tool for exposing your local development environment to external services like Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html).

In answer to your other question, you cannot supply your TwiML in the API request to Twilio. You need to have a server that Twilio can request the TwiML from when the call connects.

Comment: thanks @philnash for your answer. Looks like bit complicated to get status callbacks in my Java app. Better I will use the PHP scripts for the callback being the easiest method.

Comment: You don't have to give up on Java yet! Here's a [tutorial on sending and receiving messages in Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/java/servlets) that might help make things clearer. Or the [quick start guide for Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms) might help too.

Comment: Thanks @philnash. The links you referred mentions about how to receive SMS or calls. What exactly I want to do is to make a call to user and want to get the result of the call, whether its connected or buy or user didn't picked up, so that I can mark it in my database accordingly. Like if the number of busy or user didn't picked up the call, I want to know that feedback result in java itself but the API takes only the Callback URL, no callback events for java from which I made the call.

Comment: No, it's not based on callbacks within the language as the callbacks themselves happen asynchronously. So, you need to implement a web server that can receive those webhooks. When you create the call you will get a callSid which is the ID. When you receive a webhook you will get all the details about the call that you need including the callSid, so that you can match it up to things in your database. You can see all the details on Twilio's requests to you here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request